# XPATH expression for finding a non-empty node element data

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to find a(only one) XML node which is having non-empty data. How to do this.

**XML:**

```
<root>
<tuple >
    <old>
        <a>
            <b></b>
        </a>
    </old>
</tuple>
<tuple >
    <old>
        <a>
            <b>http://google.com</b>
        </a>
    </old>
</tuple>
<tuple >
    <old>
        <a>
            <b>http://google.com</b>
        </a>
    </old>
</tuple>
</root>
```

**XPATH I used:**

```
/root/tuple/old/a/b[text() and not(//a/b/text())]
```

and

```
/root/tuple/old/a/b[string-length(text())>0]/text()
```

But for the above xpath expressions I am getting all the nodes which are non-empty, What I am doing wrong.

Comment: in this example _all_ the elements except the first `b` are non-empty because they contain whitespace text nodes (the new lines and indentation).

Answer (score 4):

You could use following XPath

```
/root/tuple/old/a/b[normalize-space(.) = ''][1]
```

I presume that whitespaces are not important for you (so I use `normalize-space()` function). The dot means actual element (i.e. `<b>`).

As you say you need just only one element so for the case there are more suitable elements I select only the first one (`[1]`)

Comment: You've got the test backwards - you're finding the empty `b` elements rather than the non-empty ones. And (when that's fixed) it will still give you two results (the second and third `b` elements) because they're both the first non-empty `b` in their respective parents. If you only want one result you need parentheses `(/root/tuple/old/a/b[normalize-space()])[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Xpath to check if the element has value.

```
boolean(/root/tuple[position()=2]/old/a/b[text() and string-length()>0])
```

The above path returns true if the  element has text

Remove the boolean function to get the actual text as shown below.

```
/root/tuple[position()=2]/old/a/b[text() and string-length()>0]
```

Hope this helps.